# If CPT 'coins' has content else "" (wordpress cptui)

Tags: wordpress

Im looking for a solution where I use an if else statement.. So the if statement must check if there is content in de CPT else give html. I had something but that doesnt work.

I use WP (latest version), CPT UI (latest version).
CPT = Coins

```
If cptui coins has content {
CPT UI = Coins then show content / description
} else {
give html
}
```

Regards Dutchy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok find it out myself did it like so and now it does work perfectly:

```
            <?php
                $mypost = get_post();
                echo apply_filters('the_content',$mypost->post_content);
              if ( !empty( $mypost->post_content ) ) {
                the_content();
              } else {
                echo '<p ng-bind-html="ctrl.Coin.descriptionhtml"></p>';
              }
            ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this if it's on single-coins.php

```
if ( !empty( get_the_content() ) ) {
the_content();
} else {
echo "HTML PART";
}
```

Comment: I do using this with else ng-bind however it still gives me the ng-bind content. However in WP my description / content isn't empty.

Comment: You didn't mention that. Also glad you used my solution although you downvoted.